# Create new price attribute type

Tags: attributes, price, layered-navigation

I have added a new attribute called `m2_price` and populated all the products with the correct values.

However, the issue I am having is with the Layered navigation. In the layered navigation the m2_price filters are shown as follows:

```
£0 - £10
£10 - £20
£20 - £30
£30 - £40
and so on...
```

However, this needs to work exactly the same as the price filter, so it should show:

```
£0 - £9.99
£10 - £19.99
£20 - £29.99
£30 - £39.99
```

But I can't figure out how to do this, I've tried overriding `Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_Filter_Decimal` to extend `Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_Filter_Price` calling the parent for each method but this didn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you check this settings?
System > Configuration > Catalog > Layered navigation section > Price Navigation Step Calculation
Change it to "Manual" and set your value as per your requirement and check if that work for you.

Comment: This won't work because Magento only uses the `price` field, I've created a new attribute called `m2_price` which is a decimal value.